# Can't to sum array elements?

Tags: java, android

I'm very new in Android programming, and i'm trying to sum all char elements from datepicker, but with no success.

here is code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        final int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
        final int month = dp.getMonth();
        final int year = dp.getYear();

        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int num = 0;
                String sdate = String.valueOf(month) + String.valueOf(day) + String.valueOf(year);

                char[] c = sdate.toCharArray();


                for(int i=0; i<c.length;i++)
                {
                    num+=Integer.valueOf(c[i]);
                }

                tv.setText(String.valueOf(num));
            }
        });

    }
```

and output is: **355.**

Real sum must to be **20**, i want to sum like this 17/06/2013,
**so example 1+7+0+6+2+0+1+3 = 20**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [Character.getNumericValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28int%29)

```
for(int i=0; i<c.length;i++) {
     num+=Character.getNumericValue(c[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks, works :)

I have another question, when i change date, month, and year on datepicker and press button, nothings gonna change? Why?

Example: i had 17/06/2013, and i change that to 15/02/2013, result is same 19 why?

Comment: you should call [dp.init](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init(int, int, int, android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener) and register the OnDateChangedListener. When you change the onDateChanged callback will be fired.

Answer (score 1):

Change from Integer.valueOf() to Character.valueOf() Integer.valueOf(int) takes integer, your char is being cast to int and gives ASCII value.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    final int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
    final int month = dp.getMonth();
    final int year = dp.getYear();

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int num = 0;
            String sdate = String.valueOf(month) + String.valueOf(day) + String.valueOf(year);

            int[] ee=new int[sdate.length()];
            String[] dd=new String[sdate.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<sdate.length();i++){
            dd[i]=sdate.substring(i,i+1);
            ee[i]=Integer.parseInt(dd[i]);
            num+=ee[i];

    }        

            tv.setText(String.valueOf(num));
        }
    });

}
```